# clearcase: How to remove checked in file from the activity branch

Tags: clearcase

I have checked in one file say "main.c" in my activity branch. Now I want to remove this checked in file i.e. "main.c" from my activity branch. How can I remove this file from my activity branch.

As I want to deliver some files to the main line from my activity branch but I don't want to deliver this file i.e. "main.c" to the main line. That's why i want to remove this file from my activity branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[Moving a UCM version in a change set from one activity to another](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124923)"

You can open the properties of an activity, select the version of the file you want to move, and click "Move to Activity..."

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124923&aid=2]

Or you can do it in command-line with [`cleartool chact`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chactivity.htm):

```
cleartool chact -fcset anActivity -tcset aNEWActivity M:\MyDynamicView\avob\path\afile.txt@@\main\abranch\1
```

You meed to make sure `aNEWActivity` exists before the move.

That way, you can deliver `anActivity` without deliverying `aNEWActivty`, so without delivery the version of the file you have moved in it.

Comment: just to confirm one thing.....In the command cleartool chact, "aNEWActivity" will be my activity branch name or it is a keyword

Comment: @vivek aNEWActivity is just a name of a new activity you have to create first. It does not have to be your branch activity: you can keep your current activity as the branch one.

Comment: why we need to create a new activity. What will happen after creating a new activity. Please explain it in detail

Comment: @vivek You need to create a new activity in order to move the version you don't want to deliver in that new activity.

Comment: I understood...Thanks a lot.....Please clarify one more doubt for me....Creating an new activity is same as creating activity branch or it is different.....like for creating an activity branch I use "ct mkbrtype -nc branch_name"....... are you saying that I should create a new activity branch and move that file from my current activity branch to new activity branch....or creating an new activity is a different thing...

Comment: @vivek create a new activity is not the same as a new branch. Use `cleartool mkact`: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkactivity.htm. Use the `-nset` option in order for that new activity to *not* be set to your branch.